# How to maximize research in Illyriad

Tags: illyriad

How can I maximize my research in Illyriad?  I've noticed that I can't build but one library (presumably per city), and upgrading it is slow.  Is there anything else that effects research produced?

Answer (score 2):

Other alternate routes to research points are:

1. You can trade for books from the marketplace (if you've built a marketplace and at least one caravan) and you can then turn these books back into research points in your Library's Reading Room.  Note that it takes 25 research to create a book, but they only convert back to 20 research, so it's not a great way of transferring research between cities (or buying research).
2. The Moon phase affects research gained. Full Moon is very positive for Mana but negative for research, and New Moon is very negative for mana and positive for research (with the phases inbetween balancing mana/research in different ways).

There's an (incomplete) but growing (unofficial) Illyriad wiki here, that might be of help!  http://illyriad.honoredsoft.com/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: Out of curiosity are you a GM or something there?

Answer (score 0):

After completing the heroic human statues quest, you unlock allembine research which is worth 5 research p/h per level of the library